# Doing so vs Doing otherwise

Tags: word-choice

While the wording in the below examples is not ideal, would it be correct in assuming (2) would be the best answer?

(1) Make sure to cut the cable at the correct length and do not re-use old cable. Doing **so** could result in damage to the equipment.

(2) Make sure to cut the cable at the correct length and do not re-use old cable. Doing **otherwise** could result in damage to the equipment.

Do XXX and don't do XXX. Doing XXX will cause...

Do XXX and don't do XXX. Not doing XXX will cause...

Comment: Better to use different variables, as "XXX = XXX", for example *"Do x and don't do y. Not doing x/y will cause... "*

Comment: I would understand _doing so_ to refer to _re-using old cable_. _Otherwise_ is confusing.

Comment: Key question for #1 and #2 is what do *so* and *otherwise* refer back to? I'm in the otherwise camp, but it does make the reader think too hard.

Comment: The texts are inherently ambiguous. As @YosefBaskin says, both ***so*** and ***otherwise*** could refer to EITHER ***re-use old cable*** OR to the entirety of the preceding / containing sentence. So both texts could carry both meanings (the sensible one AND the stupid one). It's essentially the same as *Nellie washed the dishes in the sink*, where ***in the sink*** could refer to EITHER ***the dishes*** OR the entirety of the containing clause ***Nellie washed the dishes***.

Comment: Three Xs stand for hardcore pornography; it's funny but distracting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing so vs Doing otherwise

In example 1 :

> Make sure to cut the cable at the correct length and do not re-use old cable. **Doing so** could result in damage to the equipment.

Doing so :

> to do what has just been mentioned [Macmillan Dictionary]

The instructor is suggesting a worker to cut the wire in a correct length and to not re use a cable as doing so *(re-using a old cable)* could result in equipment damage.

In example 2 :

> Make sure to cut the cable at the correct length and do not re-use old cable. **Doing otherwise** could result in damage to the equipment.

Doing otherwise:

> Performing in a different way or manner [Merriam Webster]

The instructor is suggesting a worker to cut the wire in correct length and to not reuse a old cable as doing otherwise *(cutting a wire in the wrong length and re-using a old wire)* could result in equipment damage.

I think "**doing otherwise**"  is better as it covers both the requirements/instructions:

- Cutting the wire in correct length
- To not reuse an old cable

for a successful act, without any equipment damage.

While "doing so" only covers one of the instruction.

Comment: Commonsense indicates that meaning, but logically 'doing otherwise than _not_ re-using an old cable' would mean re-using an old cable!